# c function return loses precision

Tags: c, function, return, precision

I have a function called dump in file1.c.

```
void dump(unsigned long val, unsigned char raw){

  unsigned long dec = 0;

  dec = hex(val);

}
```

hex function is in file2.c.

```
unsigned long hex(unsigned long hex){
   unsigned long result;
...
   return result;

}
```

For some reason dec variable contains only 2 Bytes of data. If I place the hex function in the same file as dump function it contains all of data.
dec variable is local variable and not used anywhere else.
Does anybody know why this is happening?

If I put the hex function in file1.c, it gives the correct output. So the logic in the hex function is working.

Comment: we would need to see the code of `hex`

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._

Comment: Something about `unsigned long hex` tells me that the OP is confused about almost every aspect of maths and computing.

Comment: I can bet that if you compile with warnings your compiler will tell you exactly what's wrong. Specifically that you don't have prototype for hex in file1.c.

Comment: Are you experiencing this on a 16bit system?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This might be a linking issue, not picking up `hex()` from the right file. Try linking without `file2.o` and it should complain about the missing function.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe OP also didn't understand the concept behind hexadecimal numbers